# How to turn a number recognized as string to number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers

I have thousands of rows of data which have a space every three digits (e.g. 100 000 000), excel recognizes them as strings. How can I convert these to numbers? I have different amount of digits, and thus I do not believe that using left and right commands would work.

Comment: Are you attempting to convert these numbers via formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", ""))
```

[image]

Or select cells with data, press Ctrl+H. In "Find what" enter space symbol. "Replace with" leave blank and press "Replace all".

Comment: a shorter approach would be: `1*SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", "")`

Comment: Very good point